# Rails nested attributes javascript add another

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I had a model with some nested attributes and needed to add new items via Javascript. This is what I came up with:

```
$('.add_task').click(function() {
  var last_item = $('#tasks li:last');
  last_item.after('<li>'+last_item.html().replace(/\d+(?=\_)|\d+(?=\])/g, function(match) {return parseInt(match)+1;})+'</li>');
});
```

It does the job just fine, but was wondering if anyone has a better suggestion.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Ryan Bates' [complex-form-examples](http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples) repo on GitHub -- he has a few options in different branches and even an unobtrusive version using JQuery (my favorite).

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a more generic function:

```
function add_new_item(element) {
  var e = $(element);
  var tag = e.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();

  e.after(
    $('<'+tag+'>'+'</'+tag+'>').append(e.html().replace(/\d+(?=\_)|\d+(?=\])/g, function(match) {return parseInt(match)+1;}))
  );
}
```